# you need to enable javascript even thought first time running on port works fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

basically if I `npm start` for the first time it works fine.

after that it doesn't work and show that message unless I

```
netstat -ano | findstr :3000
tskill typeyourPIDhere
```

I tried many solutions but nothing worked

the issue I have started when I used `npm run build`, am I missing something or did something corrupt and not show or what happened?

Comment: What do your start and build scripts run?

Comment: not sure I understand you. still kinda starting to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The server process isn't shutting down properly and the port remains open. There's many reasons this can happen.

Comment: how can I know which reason it is?

Comment: Depends on what the server is doing. If the server is creating a database on Mars, then when you stop the server its probably still waiting for a signal from Mars to let it know its finish with the database.